# Deploy angular 7 app with google Compute Engine and nginx - display nothing

Tags: angular, nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

after deploy my angular 7 app on google compute engine  and configure nginx with my website ip address, the routing works fine (i see it in the address bar..) but nothing display on screen and get an error **502 Bad Gateway**, please any idea?

```
    nginx config:
   server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name COMPUTE_ENGINE_INSTANCE_EXTERNAL_IP;

    location / {
        root /home/path/dist;
        index index.html index.htm;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `sudo journalctl --follow _SYSTEMD_UNIT=nginx.service` and see what's going in the console when you make a request. Also you can try to set up the error logging to debug following these steps

1. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
2. find the line error_log
3. change error level to debug `logs/error.log debug`;
4. `sudo service nginx restart`

.

Comment: Hi Juan, this is the output of error log, now i get : "Invalid Host Header" hc busy: 0000000000000000 0  reusable connection: 1, recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the line that starts with server_name